# Power BI paginated reports subscription failure

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

I created subscription for paginated reports in Power BI for some end users. Some of them fails frequently. I have to manually open the subscription page and click on "send now" to send the reports. Since I was the one who set up the subscription so it is just me who receives the notification via email when the subscription fails. Is there a way to set up some group email or some other developers email as well who could receive the notification when the subscription fails even when I set up the subscription?

I searched for an option to add more developers email to receive the failure notifications but could not find any.